# SQL Server - NTEXT columns and string manipulation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, string

I have a table with an `NTEXT` column called `comments`. I have a second string, let's call it `anothercomment` (a `varchar`) that needs placing inside a given `comments` string after the word `UPDATEHERE`.

Casting to `nvarchar(max)` truncates the `comments` string, so I cannot use the likes of `CHARINDEX()` (`Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 2
String or binary data would be truncated.)`. I have used `datalength()` to check that there are a few thousand columns that are >8000 characters.

An example of what I want to achieve (albeit with much longer strings):

> comments - `This is a test UPDATEHERE This is the end of the test`
>
> anothercomment - `. This is inserted.`
>
> Resulting string -  `This is a test UPDATEHERE. This is inserted.  This is the end of the test`

I realize that this is trivial with a normal `varchar()`/`nvarchar()`, but `ntext` is a complete and utter nightmare to work with. I realize it's a deprecated data type, but I did not write the application in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting to `nvarchar(max)` should work unless you are doing something wrong with your `CHARINDEX()`

Try this code snippet, it should output what you want.

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhilsTable](
    [comment] [ntext] NULL,
    [anothercomment] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];

GO

-- insert very long string
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PhilsTable] (comment, anothercomment) VALUES (N'This is a test UPDATEHERE This is the end of the test' + REPLICATE (CAST(N'x' AS nvarchar(max)), 1000000), 'this goes in here');

-- verify data
SELECT DATALENGTH(comment), *  FROM [dbo].[PhilsTable];

-- perform replace
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(comment AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'UPDATEHERE','UPDATEHERE' + anothercomment) AS NTEXT) FROM [dbo].[PhilsTable];

DROP TABLE [dbo].[PhilsTable];
```

Thanks go out to [Andriy M](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m) for helping out with the `REPLICATE` statement.

Answer (score 10):

Converting to `nvarchar(max)` and back to `ntext` does make life simpler from a code point of view, but it does mean converting and rewriting the whole (perhaps very large) value, with all the CPU and logging overhead that implies.

An alternative is to use [`UPDATETEXT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx). This is deprecated, just like `ntext`, but it can reduce the logging overhead significantly. On the downside, it means using text pointers, and it only operates on one row at a time.

The following example code uses a cursor to work around that limitation, and uses `PATINDEX` instead of `CHARINDEX` since the former is one of the [few functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) that work directly with `ntext`:

#### Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PhilsTable
(
    comment ntext NULL,
    anothercomment nvarchar(50) NULL
);

INSERT dbo.PhilsTable
    (comment, anothercomment)
VALUES 
(
    CONVERT(ntext, 
        N'This is a test UPDATEHERE This is the end of the test ' + 
            REPLICATE (CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'x'), 1000000)), 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(50), N'. This is inserted.')
),
(
    CONVERT(ntext, 
        N'This is a test UPDATEHERE This is the end of the test ' + 
            REPLICATE (CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'x'), 1000000)), 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(50), N'. This is inserted.')
),
(
    CONVERT(ntext, 
        N'This is a test UPDATEHERE This is the end of the test ' + 
            REPLICATE (CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'x'), 1000000)), 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(50), N'. This is inserted.')
);
```

#### Cursor declaration

```
DECLARE c 
    CURSOR GLOBAL 
    FORWARD_ONLY 
    DYNAMIC 
    SCROLL_LOCKS 
    TYPE_WARNING
FOR
SELECT
    TxtPtr = TEXTPTR(PT.comment),
    Src = PT.anothercomment,
    Offset = PATINDEX(N'%UPDATEHERE%', PT.comment) + LEN(N'UPDATEHERE') - 1
FROM dbo.PhilsTable AS PT
WHERE
    PT.comment LIKE N'%UPDATEHERE%'; -- LIKE works with ntext

OPEN c;
```

#### Processing loop

```
DECLARE 
    @Ptr binary(16),
    @Src nvarchar(50),
    @Offset integer;

SET STATISTICS XML OFF; -- No cursor fetch plans

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH c INTO @Ptr, @Src, @Offset;

        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -2 CONTINUE; -- row missing
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK; -- no more rows

        IF 1 = TEXTVALID('dbo.PhilsTable.comment', @Ptr)
        BEGIN
            -- Modify ntext value
            UPDATETEXT dbo.PhilsTable.comment @Ptr @Offset 0 @Src;
        END;
    END;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;
```